# Xamarin Issue : error XA2002: Can not resolve reference: `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions` referenced by `System.Reactive`

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

I need help for Xamarin Form. I have a Xamarin Application has developed in Visual Studio 2017 (Version 15.9.13). I am facing the compiling error as below. I have updated my code with the latest version from Git updated by other team member. After that I am not able to compile.

error XA2002: Can not resolve reference: `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`, referenced by `System.Reactive`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`, or remove the reference to `System.Reactive`.

I have tried to install the below library by NuGet but the same error.

1. System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions (4.6.0-preview.18571.3)
2. System.Reactive.Linq (4.2.0-preview.566)
3. System.Reactive (4.2.0-preview.566)

I have already updated my VS2017 with latest version.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1898,2): error XA2002: Can not resolve reference: `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`, referenced by `System.Reactive`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`, or remove the reference to `System.Reactive`.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Preview builds instead of stable builds? Also could you please share more of your error log?

Comment: Hi Saamer, This is the latest build so  have installed that. I have also tried with the stable build then the same result. I ave tried 3 to 4 different version of build.

Comment: Could you please provide the diagnostic MSBuild log output?

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these:

1. Downgrading `System.Threading.Tasks.Extension` from 4.5.1 to 4.4.0 and using it with:

   - `System.Reactive 4.1.0 (latest)`
   - `System.Reactive.Interfaces 4.1.0 (latest)`
   - `System.Reactive.Linq 4.1.0( latest)`
   - `System.Reactive.PlatformServices (latest)`
   - `System.Threading 4.3.0 (latest)`
   - `System.Threading.Taks 4.3.0 (latest)`
   - `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.4.0 (downgraded)`
2. Keep `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions` upgraded, installing `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` to all Android, iOS, and UWP projects, and downgrading System.Reactive to version 4.0.0

But also, consider switching to VS 2019, all release versions of VS 2019 (including for Mac) should come with a fixed version of Xamarin.Android now.